# Splitting strings with unescaped separator in R

Tags: regex, r

I have to read a file with R, where a variable number of columns is separated by the `|` character. However, if it is preceded by a `\` it should not be considered a separator.

I first thought something like `strsplit(x, "[^\\][|]")` would work, but the problem here is that the character before each pipe is "consumed":

```
> strsplit("word1|word2|word3\\|aha!|word4", "[^\\][|]")
[[1]]
[1] "word"        "word"        "word3\\|aha" "word4"
```

Can anyone suggest a way to do this? Ideally it should be vectorized since the files in question are very large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this works; using Anirudh's downvoted answer (not sure why the downvote, it doesn't work but the regex was correct)

```
strsplit(x, "(?<!\\\\)[|]", perl=TRUE)

## > strsplit(x, "(?<!\\\\)[|]", perl=TRUE)
## [[1]]
## [1] "word1"        "word2"        "word3\\|aha!" "word4"
```

Comment: This nails it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [zero width assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)(lookbehind)

```
(?<!\\\\)[|]
```

Comment: This might be correct as far as regex go, but it will require some modification to work in R (even setting `perl = TRUE`), and I'm not sure what those modifications will be. (I mean this literally, this regex throws an error in R.)

Comment: @joran have you set `perl` parameter to TRUE.

Comment: Did you read my comment? It throws an error for me either way.